# Delete all the rows from System.Data.Entity in MVC5 in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, api

As I run the system. Every time the user visits the: http://localhost:54619/People/Index I would like all the date to be deleted form the database and then new data to be added.

However, I cannot find a way to work that out.

The records are being read from a Json file and then will be added to the database.

```
    // GET: People
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (db.People.Count() > 0)
        {
            int NumRows = db.People.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < NumRows; i++)
            {
                Person person = db.People.Find(i+1);
                db.People.Remove(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            string Json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Output.json");
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var personlist = ser.Deserialize<List<Person>>(Json);
            db.People.AddRange(personlist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            return View(db.People.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            string Json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Output.json");
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var personlist = ser.Deserialize<List<Person>>(Json);
            db.People.AddRange(personlist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(db.People.ToList());
        }

    }
```

Comment: db.People.Find( ... ) will search for the Primary Key.

Comment: Why bother with the database at all if you are reading from a file to replace the database every time?  Just serve up the contents of your file...  I realize that "read from a file" may be a placeholder from "refresh the database in some other way", but it still seems unidiomatic to have a get request for the collection replace the collection in the database.

Comment: Don't do SaveChanges() inside a loop, it's overkill for performance. Instead make all the delete operations and call SaveChanges outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.People.RemoveRange(db.People.ToList());
db.SaveChanges():
```

Answer (score -1):

Markus's answer should work. But it's horribly inefficient. It loads all rows from the database before starting to delete those roles. If there are a lot of rows, it takes time to query them from the database and send the data to the database client.

For these type of tasks, just use `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` to run a query against the database. LINQ is great, but not for everything.

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM People");
```

Comment: True, but Markus’ code is DB independent whereas yours won’t work on Postgres for example where you would need to escape table/column names if they include capital letters.